# Accessing javascript variable in dojo module

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am creating a module with dojo. This module is about configuration.

```
define(["geometry/Point"], function (Point) {
        var sp = new Point(122, -142);
        return {            
            startPoint: new Point(122, -142),
            globalOptions: {
                logo: false,
                center: sp
            },

        };
    })
```

In this module, if I use **sp** varible as center, code is working. But if I use center as start point, the center is coming null. Like following

```
define(["geometry/Point"], function (Point) {
        return {            
            startPoint: new Point(122, -142),
            globalOptions: {
                logo: false,
                center: this.startPoint
            },

        };
    })
```

I deleted the varible **sp** and used **this.startPoint** but center is coming null.

Comment: And what is your question? You cannot reference properties of the object during definition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're referencing the wrong object. If you use `this` at the `center` property, you're actually not referencing to your module anymore. Because you're instantiating a new object, it will actually refer to the global object, which is (if you're using a browser) `window`.

Your first solution works because `sp` is scoped so that it can be accessed from your module as well as from your `globalOptions` property.

---

EDIT (as requested from the comments):

To declare a module to access its functions you should use:

```js
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/_base/array"], function(declare, lang, array) {
    return declare(null, {
        param: ["a", "b", "c"],
        action: function() {
            this.otherAction(); // Call other action
        },
        otherAction: function() {
            array.forEach(this.param, lang.hitch(this, "lastFunction"));
        },
        lastFunction: function(item, idx) {
            console.log(idx + " " + item);
        }
    });
});
```

This example shows some basics in Dojo. To create a module you should use `dojo/_base/declare`. The first parameter `null` is to define a list of inherited modules, in this case none.

Parameters and functions can be declared in a similar way. Calling a function from another function should be done by providing the context `this`, for example `this.otherAction()`.

If you lose the `this` context, you can use `lang.hitch()`. It in fact calls the function, but preserves the context. That's what I do with `lang.hitch(this, "lastFunction")`.

I can explain it even more, but I think it would be useful to read [this tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modules/).

Comment: It's true that `this` points to the wrong object, but it most likely refers to `window`. It certainly does not refer to `globalOptions` or the object returned by the function. You cannot reference an object during its definition.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know that, modified my answer.

Comment: How can I declare a module to Access its functions?

Comment: I explained some basics in Dojo for declaring modules in my answer.

Comment: Great explanation. It is very much useful to me. Also explanaing the syntax to declare module is good.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do somthing like this,

```
define(["geometry/Point"], function (Point) {
        return {            
            startPoint: new Point(122, -142),
            globalOptions: {},

            postCreate: function () {
            this.globalOptions = {
            logo: false,
            center: this.startPoint
            }

          }    
        };
    })
```

this issue occurs because of scope of this..

hope this will help you..

Comment: This probably won't work since you're not inheriting from anything. `postCreate` is not a default function, but it's actually a hook defined by `dijit/_WidgetBase`.

Comment: @DimitriM thanks, i know we need to inherit base widget or base class for this.. and this was only a sample so i didn,t go to the deep..

Comment: I was only mentioning it for other people who would use this code and notice that `globalOptions` isn't initialized. ;) But what would you do if this module isn't a widget. As far as I see, `geometry/Point` has no intent to be a widget, so inheriting `_WidgetBase` would not suffit.

Comment: Have you any suggestion to Access functions of a modüle? How can I declare it?

Comment: @youtubeline, for accessing a function this may be helpfull... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126407/javascript-modular-layout-how-to-call-a-function-defined-in-one-module-from-an

Comment: for module detail structure i have added an answere below.. lets see if that is helpfull for you.... otherwise feel free to shoot your queries:)

Answer (score 1):

**Modules**

The two key concepts you need to be aware of here are the idea of a *define* method for facilitating module definition and a *require* method for handling dependency loading. define is used to define named or unnamed modules based on the proposal using the following signature:

```
    define(
    module_id /*optional*/,
    [dependencies] /*optional*/,
    definition function /*function for instantiating the module or object*/
    );
```

As you can tell by the inline comments, the module_id is an optional argument which is typically only required when non-AMD concatenation tools are being used (there may be some other edge cases where it's useful too). When this argument is left out, we call the module anonymous.

When working with anonymous modules, the idea of a module's identity is DRY, making it trivial to avoid duplication of filenames and code. Because the code is more portable, it can be easily moved to other locations (or around the file-system) without needing to alter the code itself or change its ID. The module_id is equivalent to folder paths in simple packages and when not used in packages. Developers can also run the same code on multiple environments just by using an AMD optimizer that works with a CommonJS environment such as r.js.

Back to the define signature, the dependencies argument represents an array of dependencies which are required by the module you are defining and the third argument ('definition function') is a function that's executed to instantiate your module. A barebone module could be defined as follows:

```
// A module_id (myModule) is used here for demonstration purposes only

define('myModule',
['foo', 'bar'],
// module definition function
// dependencies (foo and bar) are mapped to function parameters
function ( foo, bar ) {
// return a value that defines the module export
// (i.e the functionality we want to expose for consumption)
// create your module here
var myModule = {
doStuff:function(){
console.log('Yay! Stuff');
}
}

return myModule;
});

// An alternative example could be..
define('myModule',
['math', 'graph'],
function ( math, graph ) {

// Note that this is a slightly different pattern
// With AMD, it's possible to define modules in a few
// different ways due as it's relatively flexible with
// certain aspects of the syntax
return {
plot: function(x, y){
return graph.drawPie(math.randomGrid(x,y));
}
}
};
});
```

*require* on the other hand is typically used to load code in a top-level JavaScript file or within a module should you wish to dynamically fetch dependencies.

```
// Consider 'foo' and 'bar' are two external modules
// In this example, the 'exports' from the two modules loaded are passed as
// function arguments to the callback (foo and bar)
// so that they can similarly be accessed

require(['foo', 'bar'], function ( foo, bar ) {
// rest of your code here
foo.doSomething();
});
```

hoping this is helpfull for you...

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach was the correct one, but you had a bit of duplication that you didn't need in the `startPoint` definition:

```
function test() {

    var startPoint = "x,y"

    return {            
        startPoint: startPoint,            
        globalOptions: {
            logo: false,
            center: startPoint
        }
    };
}

console.log(test().startPoint)
console.log(test().globalOptions)
```

Test in JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/IxENEkA/1/edit

Comment: That's  what the OP has, so what's the point? *edit:* Ok, I see the difference now. However, maybe creating two `Point` objects was intentional.

Comment: + I've added a jsbin everyone can re-use.